# Start up a web-service in a windows-based application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis, windows-services

I have a quite old web-service (asmx) that run well on IIS. Now there is a need of start this up in a windows-based application e.g. a console application (or perhaps in a windows service)

Is there any way of hosting the current ASMX project in a console application without modifying this? Unfortunatelly we cannot convert this in a WCF.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: instead of hosting the current ASMX Project inside the Console Application, can't you just add a web service reference to the web service from the Windows Form/Console Project's solution ?

Comment: Self hosting is only supports by latest technologies such as WCF/ASP.NET Web API. You are out of luck.

Comment: @LexLi What a pitty! Unfortunately I see no easy way of converting into a WCF service. It's a legacy that has hundreds of TypedDataSets which are painful to be rewritten. Anyway, thanks for the answer!